# Puppet - how to pass arguments to the command line

Tags: ruby, puppet, devops

I am newbie to puppet and I wonder how I can pass arguments to the command line. I will explain myself:

This is the command that I'm running (puppet apply):

C:>puppet apply --environment test -l C:\Puppet_logs\log.log C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\test\manifests\site.pp

Site.pp:

```
File { backup => false }
node default {
include 'tn'
}
```

It means that I am running 'tn' which is one of the modules in my puppet project.

For example, 
I have these modules in my puppet project:

tn

ps

av

So to run each module I need to go to this site.pp file and change it to

include 'ps'

or

include 'av'

***My question is -***

How do I pass these modules as arguments to the puppet apply command?

I know that I can create 3 .pp files that each one contains one module (ps, av, tn)

And then my command will look like:

puppet apply --environment test -l C:\Puppet_logs\log.log C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\test\manifests\ps.pp

puppet apply --environment test -l C:\Puppet_logs\log.log C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\test\manifests\av.pp

puppet apply --environment test -l C:\Puppet_logs\log.log C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\test\manifests\tn.pp

But, I think it's not a good solution..
Is there another way to pass these modules as arguments to the puppet apply?
If I didn't mention - each module is responsible for different actions.

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can create 3 .pp files that each one contains one module
>   (ps, av, tn)
>
> [...]
>
> But, I think it's not a good solution.

Why isn't it a good solution?  It seems perfectly sensible to me that if you have three different things you want to be able to do, then you have a separate file to use to accomplish each.

Nevertheless, if your modules do not use each other, then you could probably accomplish what you describe by relying on tags.  Have your site manifest include all three modules:

```
File { backup => false }
node default {
  include 'tn'
  include 'ps'
  include 'av'
}
```

Then use the `--tags` option to select only one of those modules and all the other classes it brings in:

```
puppet apply --tags ps --environment test -l C:\Puppet_logs\log.log C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\test\manifests\site.pp
```

Answer (score 0):

A pp file is a class file not a module, a module contains the classes and anything else needed to support/test those classes, take a look at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/modules_fundamentals.html.

Look at how modules are laid out on https://forge.puppet.com/

It’s well worth looking at the PDK https://puppet.com/docs/pdk/1.x/pdk.html as it'll build a module for you, you just need to add the classes.

In your case you probably want to create a new module (let’s call it mymodule) and in that module put all your tn.pp ps.pp and av.pp class files under the C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\test\modules\mymodule\manifests directory.
Then for local testing use the examples pattern, so in your module you’ll have an examples directory and in there you might have a file called ps.pp which would contain `include mymodule::ps` to include that ps.pp class file.
The aim of the examples directory is to give you a method of passing in parameters for local testing.

Back in your site.pp file you’d apply is with:

```
Node default {
  Include mymodule::ps
}
```

So now you want to apply different classes to the nodes and there you hit the world of node classification and there are many ways you can do that. In your case I think you’re probably doing this on a small scale so you’d have;

```
Node psserver.example.com {
  Include mymodule::ps
}

Node tnserver.example.com {
  Include mymodule::tn
}
```

Have a look at some of the online training https://puppet.com/learning-training/kits/puppet-language-basics